# Find distance $d (A,B)$ between line $A$ and $B$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let:
>   $$A=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x+y=0,x+z=0\right\}$$
>   $$B=\left\{(1,t,1+2t):t \in \mathbb R\right\}$$
>   Find distance $d (A,B)$ between line $A$ and $B$.

I have a question to this task because I think that I'm making a mistake here, because then this task would be too easy:
$A$ we can write as: $$A=\left\{(x,-x,-x):x\in \mathbb R\right\}$$
So the point $(1,-1,-1)$ is in $A$ and $B$. 
That's why: $$d(A,B)=\inf \left\{|a-b|:a\in A, b\in B\right\}=\inf \left\{|(1,-1,-1)-(1,-1,-1)|\right\}=0$$However I think that this sollution is too trivial to be true.

Comment: I believe the question is asking about finding the general distance between $A$ and $B$ . $(1,-1,-1) $ is only the point of intersection and do not represent the lines but two  points.

Comment: Your solution is right, two intersecting lines have zero distance, and it suffices to exhibit the common point. Notice that your second $\inf$ doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok, thanks. Yes, I know that $inf$ doesn't make sense but I wanted to show that understand this task just in case if I had a good feeling I was making a mistake somewhere

Comment: You can try to solve it with e.g. $B'=\{(1,t,2+2t):t\in\Bbb R\}$.